# datatool: How to reliably store database in \AtEndDocument (or similar hook)

Tags: auxiliary-files, datatool, hooks

In a big report with many subfiles and authors, I am using the `datatool` package to write out some data collected across the document. At the end of the document, the data should be stored in a CSV file with `\DTLsavedb`. For this, I am currently using the `\AtEndDocument` hook.

The problem is that this does not work reliably. From looking into the `datatool` sources, I think this is because `datatool` does not write out to the file `\immediate`, so that the writing is delayed until shipout time. However, if there is no remaining content to shipout at the end of the document, the file never gets written.

I could try to patch `datatool` to use `\immediate`, however, I with respect to performance, the delayed writing is probably a good thing. So a better solution would probably be to somehow make sure that at the end of the document all outstanding data gets written independently from the shipout routine? Or maybe there is a "last page hook" I could use instead of `\AtEndDocument`?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DTLgnewdb{importantguys}%
}
\AtEndDocument{%
  \DTLsavedb{importantguys}{importantguys.csv}%
}

\newcommand{\importantguy}[2]{%
  \DTLnewrow{importantguys}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{importantguys}{firstname}{#1}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{importantguys}{surname}{#1}%
  \paragraph{#1 #2:}%
}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum
  \importantguy{Foo}{Bar} does cool stuff.
  \importantguy{Computer}{Mouse} is really important for the project.
  \lipsum
  \importantguy{Becky}{Brewer} helps to keep us running.
  \clearpage
\end{document}
```

Comment: The main problem is that when LaTeX issues its final `\clearpage` to clear all queues and possibly shipout other pages, it's not known whether an actual `\shipout` will be performed. One could think of using `\AtVeryEndDocument` (package `atveryend`) and changing there `datatool`'s `\write` to `\immediate\write`. A `\write` that's not `\immediate` is performed *only* during shipout.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Deferred writing and package `atenddvi`

Package `atenddvi` provides the hook `\AtEndDvi` to get stuff written at the shipout of the last page. Two LaTeX runs are needed at least for knowing, which is the last page. Despite the name the output type DVI, PDF or whatever does not matter.

### Immediate writing and package `atveryend`

If your data does not contain data that require deferred writing, then `\DTLsaveddb` can be patched to immediate mode as shown in the following example. It also uses package `atveryend` with hook `\AtVeryEnd` for the case that someone adds an important guy via `\AtEndDocument`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{atveryend}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \DTLgnewdb{importantguys}%
}
\AtVeryEndDocument{%
  \begingroup
    \let\SavedOpenout\openout
    \let\SavedWrite\write
    \def\openout{\immediate\SavedOpenout}%
    \def\write{\immediate\SavedWrite}%
    \DTLsavedb{importantguys}{importantguys.csv}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\importantguy}[2]{%
  \DTLnewrow{importantguys}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{importantguys}{firstname}{#1}%
  \DTLnewdbentry{importantguys}{surname}{#2}%
  \paragraph{#1 #2:}%
}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum
  \importantguy{Foo}{Bar} does cool stuff.
  \importantguy{Computer}{Mouse} is really important for the project.
  \lipsum
  \importantguy{Becky}{Brewer} helps to keep us running.
  \clearpage
\end{document}
```

File `importantguys.csv`:

> ```
> firstname,surname
> Foo,Bar
> Computer,Mouse
> Becky,Brewer
> ```

Comment: Thanks Heiko, that seems to work! BTW: The first thing I was wondering was if `\AtEndDvi` does also work in PDF mode. To avoid confusion, I edited the respective sentence from your package docs into the answer.